# ReduxToolkit - createAsyncTask Get Data after Post

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm pretty new to reduxtoolkit and I'm creating a basic app where it connects to the backend service.

I have this following codes for fetching and adding data:

```
export const getFruits = createAsyncThunk("food/fruits", async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('/api/food/')
        return response.data
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})

export const addFruit = createAsyncThunk("food/fruits", async (fruit) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post('/api/food/', fruit)
        return response.data
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

I have something for this for my `extraReducers`

```
extraReducers: {
        [getFruits.fulfilled.type]: (state, { payload }) => {
            state.list = payload
            state.status = "success"
        },
        [addFruit.fulfilled.type]: (state, { payload }) => {
            state.status = "success"
        },
    }
```

but when I try to add the `dispatch(getFruits())` inside the `[addFruit.fulfilled.type]:`, it doesn't work.

```
[addFruit.fulfilled.type]: (state, { payload }) => {
            state.status = "success"
            dispatch(getFruits) 
            // or 
            getFruits()
        },
```

What's the recommended and/or proper way to achieve it? the retrieval of

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make a **nested** usage within the slice. Call **addFruit** on any component and call **getFruits** with **.then**.

Example:

```
dispatch(addFruits(payload)).then(() => {getFruits})
```

Comment: I get the error that says: `TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'AsyncThunkAction<any, any, {}>'.`

Comment: But I found the solution to use the `appUseDispatch` No debug error that's showing but the get functionality isn't working after I called the add method.

Answer (score 0):

you should create your thunk like this

```
export const getFruits = createAsyncThunk("food/getFruits", async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('/api/food/')
        return response.data
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})

export const addFruit = createAsyncThunk("food/addFruit", async (fruit) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post('/api/food/', fruit)
        return response.data
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

and your reducer like this

```
extraReducers: {
        [getFruits.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
            state.list = payload
            state.status = "success"
        },
        [addFruit.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
            state.status = "success"
        },
    }
```

I hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: I actually have that similar setup for the api calls and reducers. But still, it doesn't work

Comment: Please look at the question

Comment: what is `[addFruit.fulfilled.type]:` you have to write it like this `[addFruit.fulfilled]:` and you did not add your add function to the thunk `createAsyncThunk("food/fruits",` you have to add it like this so the extra reducer will know about it  `createAsyncThunk("food/addFruit"`

Comment: I'm using typescript that's why it has `.type` there. It needs the `.type` in typescript file.